# Django Model Foreign Key to text

Tags: python, django, django-models

There is a problem, there is a Book model and in it title is the name of the book, and author is the ForeignKey of the Author model where there is a name field.
I need to get a Python list and for this I do
`books = list(Book.objects.values('title', 'author')`,
but the result is a list `[{'title': 'Harry Potter', 'author': 1}]`. How do I make sure that the author is instead of the unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest fix for you is `books = list(Book.objects.values('title', 'author__name')`. In the assumption that author model has name field.